# how to add and remove a class when bootstrap popup is scroll then 300px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

scroll top not working on particular div. i dont no how to fix it. please help me.i am just using window.scroll function. but its not working properly

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >=50) {
        $(".mycountry").addClass("fix");
    } else {
        $(".mycountry").removeClass("fix");
    }

});
```

```css
form-group.mycountry.fix {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: -14px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal-content {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  


----------
## 

 1. Heading

 ##

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email address:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mycountry">
              <label> country</label>
              <select class="form-control">
                <option> 1</option>
                <option> 2</option>
                <option> 3</option>
                <option> 4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
              <input type="checkbox">
              Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good thing to change input id to unique: pwd1, pwd2 etc

if you need scroll to whole popup (class="modal"):

```
$(function () {
      $('.modal').scroll(function () {
       var totop = 50;
       if ($(this).scrollTop() >= totop) {
         $(".mycountry").addClass("fix");
       } else {
         $(".mycountry").removeClass("fix");
       }
     });
});
```

if you need scroll to modal content (class="modal-content"):

```
$(function () {
  $('.modal-content').scroll(function () {
     var totop = 50;
   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= totop) {
      $(".mycountry").addClass("fix");
   } else {
      $(".mycountry").removeClass("fix");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you do much  sir. this code work for me. and i always use different id for different inputs.  i just made this demo page for help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.modal-content').scroll(function () {
     var totop = 50;
   if ($(this).scrollTop() >= totop) {
      $(".mycountry").addClass("fix");
   } else {
      $(".mycountry").removeClass("fix");
    }
  });
});
```